# Meteor alanning:roles - Error invoking Method 'updateRoles': Internal server error [500]

Tags: meteor, user-roles

I am trying to set the role for the logged in user (using [alanning:roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) package) via a method on the server. Here's what I have...

**Client**

```
var userId = Meteor.userId();
Meteor.call('updateRoles',userId,'admin');
```

And this is the simplified version of the [method from the docs](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles#roles-usage)...

**server/userMethods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateRoles: function (targetUserId, roles) {
        Roles.setUserRoles(targetUserId, roles)
    }
})
```

No matter what I try I keep getting the following error...

```
Error invoking Method 'updateRoles': Internal server error [500]
```

Comment: Note that using that Method any user can set themselves as admin.

Comment: Yes, I know, I simplified the method to ask the question as I was certain the issue was not related to the omitted code. I will be using the same method from the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The reason was because I am using autoform (simple schema) for the 'users' collection and I needed to include the following (uncommented part) in the schema...

```
// Add `roles` to your schema if you use the meteor-roles package.
// Option 1: Object type
// If you specify that type as Object, you must also specify the
// `Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP` group whenever you add a user to a role.
// Example:
// Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, ["admin"], Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
// You can't mix and match adding with and without a group since
// you will fail validation in some cases.
//
//roles: {
//    type: Object,
//    optional: true,
//    blackbox: true
//},
// Option 2: [String] type
// If you are sure you will never need to use role groups, then
// you can specify [String] as the type

roles: {
    type: [String],
    optional: true
},
```